# Add an arrow at top of vertical navigation

Tags: html, css

Basically, I am trying to get an arrow at the top of my drop down menu like this
http://dribbble.com/shots/678124-Notification-Dropdown?list=users

The problem is, I am not seeing the arrow when I add it into my page. I believe it is behind the list, but I just am stumped on how to do this in general.

My list is this

```
<ul>
        <img src=\"images/icons/listarrow.png\">
        <li><a href=\"viewuser.php?uid=$liveuserid\"><img src=\"images/profilepics/$profilepic\">Your profile</a></li>
        <li><a href=\"settings.php?personal=all\">pic Settings</a></li>
        <li><a href=\"settings.php?addproject=all\">pic Add Project</a></li>
        <li><a href=\"settings.php?mail=all\">pic Mail</a></li>
    <li><a href=\"logout.php\">Logout pic</a></li>
 </ul></li></ul>"
```

Comes from PHP code so that's why I have the escape slashes. The CSS I use for the list

```
#usernav ul ul {

background: #ecebe8; 
border-radius: 0px; 
padding: 0;
position: absolute; 
top: 37px;
margin-left: 12px;
border-top-left-radius: 10px;
border-top-right-radius: 10px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
-webkit-border-top-left-radius: 10px;
-webkit-border-top-right-radius: 10px;
-webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
-webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
-moz-border-radius-topleft: 10px;
-moz-border-radius-topright: 10px;
-moz-border-radius-bottomright: 10px;
-moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 10px;
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 4px #000;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 4px #000;
box-shadow: 0px 1px 4px #000;
/* For IE 8 */
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Strength=4, Direction=135, Color='#000000')";
/* For IE 5.5 - 7 */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Strength=4, Direction=135, Color='#000000');

}


#usernav ul ul li {

padding: 0px;
float: none; 
position: relative;;
border: 0px;
background-color: white;
min-width: 0px;
width: 135px;

}
```

I am sure the path is right, maybe my html code for adding the image is just stupid, I don't know. Thanks!

Comment: Your HTML is invalid, you should fix that first

Comment: Yeah, you have a rogue </div> tag after the <img>. That </div> shouldn't be there.

Comment: Additionally, you can't have any other element besides a `<li>` as a child of a `<ul>` or an `<li>`

Comment: Sorry about that, I deleted that

Comment: Adrift, this is a snipped of the second UL of a drop down menu

Comment: It doesn't matter - the `<img>` is still a *child* of the `<ul>` .. which is invalid in HTML

Comment: Consider a pure CSS solution? http://nicolasgallagher.com/pure-css-speech-bubbles/demo/

Comment: Adrift, thanks for recognizing that, now how do i go about having it a part of the menu and not a part of the ul?

Comment: Don't put the image in via HTML, use CSS.  There are pure CSS Solutions to this also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do this with the before pseudo element.

```
ul:before {
border-bottom: 10px solid #000;
border-left: 10px solid transparent;
border-right: 10px solid transparent;
content: "";
height: 0;
position: absolute;
right: 0;
top: -10px;
width: 0;
}
```

This will create an arrow that appears at the top of the UL. Just be sure to apply relative positioning to the appropriate parent element.

Answer (score 0):

you could give the img an id, and then set the height and width to what you want for the id in css

that should work, if not try wrapping the img in `<li></li>` tags